# Can't call Javascript object method

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I get a console error `TypeError: bodys.show is not a function` when loading my page. What am I doing wrong?

```
function loadingScreen(selector,css)
{
    this.loadingAnimation = $("<div><p>Loading</p><div></div></div>").appendTo(selector);
    this.containerCss = $.extend({'border-radius':"20px",position:"absolute",height:"40px",width:"120px","display":"none"}, css);
    this.loadingAnimation.css(this.containerCss);
    this.p = this.loadingAnimation.children("p").first();
    this.p.css({width:"100%",'text-align':"center"});
    this.div = this.loadingAnimation.children("div").first();
    this.div.css({position:"abslolute",left:"0",top:"0",'background-color':"rgba(255,100,100,0.5)",height:"100%",width:"10%"});
    function show(){
        this.loadingAnimation.css("display","block");
        animate(this.div,"right");
    }
    function hide(){
        this.loadingAnimation.css("display","none");
        this.div.stop(true,true);
        this.div.css("margin-left","0px");
    }
    function animate(element,direction)
    {
        if(direction === "right"){
            element.animate({"margin-left":"120px"},animate(element,"left"));
        }
        else if(direction === "left"){
            element.animate({"margin-left":"0px"},animate(element,"right"));
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var bodys = new loadingScreen("body",{});
    bodys.show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring variables/functions inside the body of a function, they are 'private' unless they are attached as properties of the function itself - inside the body, you'd use the `this` keyword to do this.

The function `show()` is private inside loadingScreen, to make it accessible as a member of its parent function, declare it with `this`:

```
this.show  = function(){...

...}
```

...it will still be able to access everything inside the scope of `loadingScreen`, but will be able to be called externally as a method of `loadingScreen`.

EDIT:

As Naomik points out below, you can also attach it to the prototype of the object:

```
loadingScreen.prototype.show = function()...
```

...apparently prototypal functions are executed more quickly than standard member declarations, however - as you'll be declaring it outside of the main function body, it won't have access to the private variables inside the function, so in this case it wouldn't be much use.

Comment: How do I pass parameters into the functions? Something like `this.show = function(param1,param2){}`?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same as a normal function, all you're doing is changing the declaration, the parentheses after the function keyword should contain any arguments you wish to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `show()` function is defined in the local/private scope of `loadingScreen`, in order to making `show` publicly visible use `this.show`

So change your code as

```
 this.show = function() {
```

instead of

```
function show(){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `show` to your new instance using `this.show = show;` inside your constructor

Or you can do this

```
// loading-screen.js
(function(window, $) {

  var LoadingScreen = function (selector, css) {
    this.$elem = $(selector);
    this.$elem.css(css);
  };

  LoadingScreen.prototype.show = function () {
    return this.$elem.show();
  };

  LoadingScreen.prototype.hide = function () {
    return this.$elem.hide();
  };

  window.LoadingScreen = LoadingScreen;

})(window, jQuery);
```

As part of the prototype, the `show` and `hide` functions will now be accessible to any instance of `LoadingScreen`. To top it off, you have an nice little module of code that can be included separately from all of your other scripts.

Usage

```
<script src="loading-screen.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var ls = new LoadingScreen("body", {});
    ls.show();
    ls.hide();
  });
</script>
```

---

**jQuery plugin** — [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7j3T2/)

Since you're using jQuery anyway, instead of passing a `selector` and some css to vanilla constructor function, it might make sense to wrap this up in a jQuery plugin.

```
(function(window, $) {

  var LoadingScreen = function($elems, css) {
    this.$elems = $elems;
    this.$elems.css(css);
  };

  LoadingScreen.prototype.show = function() {
    this.$elems.slideDown(250);
  };

  LoadingScreen.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.$elems.slideUp(250);
  };

  $.fn.loadingScreen = function(css) {
    return new LoadingScreen(this, css);
  };

})(window, jQuery);
```

Usage is pretty similar but looks like much more conventional jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var ls = $("p").loadingScreen({backgroundColor: "blue"});

  // notice .show and .hide delegate to our plugin methods now
  ls.show();
});
```

Comment: @MickMalone1983, neither do I. Some people just don't know better. It's okay.